# SPI module on Raspberry Pi 2 not working

Tags: spi

I followed all steps on [SPI module on Raspberry Pi 2](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/34621/spi-module-on-raspberry-pi-2), without success, no way to make this work on a Pi2...

On /boot/config/txt there is:

```
dtparam=spi=on
dtoverlay=spi-bcm2835
```

On /etc/modules:

```
spi-bcm2835
```

Blacklist file is empty. lsmod returns

```
spi_bcm2835             7216  0
```

ls /dev/spi* returns:

```
/dev/spidev0.0  /dev/spidev0.1
```

But still I get no electric activity on any SPI pin. Connected a scope on SCK pin (pin #23, GPIO11/SPI_CLK) and nothing. Tryed :

```
echo -ne "\x01\x02\x03" > /dev/spidev0.0
```

and also run the spi_test application (returns all zeroes).

Any hint on what I am doing wrong?

The Pi is running latest version of raspbian

Comment: Could you post a link to the 'other SPI module post' you mention in your first sentence?

Comment: Does it work without the /etc/modules entry? I thought the DT was an alternative way to load modules.

Comment: Yes, it is, but unfortunately I'm not quite familiar with DT syntax and wasn't able to make it work that way.

Answer (score 3):

Just adding the pi user to the spi group solved the problem:

```
sudo adduser pi spi
```

Running the spi_test program after that all went OK.

Comment: Are the pin outs different on version 1 and 2 of the pi ?